# How can I get Visual Studio to use Embedded Source code whilst debugging?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-core, pdb-files

I have embedded the C# source code into a portable PDB file using the `<EmbedAllSources>` element in the csproj file, and I have embedded the pdb into the assembly using the `<DebugType>embedded<DebugType>` as described in [Embedding C# sources in PDB with new csproj](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42714352/embedding-c-sharp-sources-in-pdb-with-new-csproj)

My assembly looks like this:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>    
    <EmbedAllSources>true</EmbedAllSources>
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>embedded</DebugType>   
</PropertyGroup>
```

I can confirm that the pdb is type portable, and contains my source code:

[image]

According to the release notes for Visual Studio 15.5 the debugger should be able to use these files during debugging:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releasenotes/vs2017-relnotes-v15.5#EmbeddedSource

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 (version number 15.8.8)

However, when I F11 into the code from my assembly it asks for the sourcecode:

[image]

Whilst googling around there's a comment from ctaggart in the discussion https://github.com/ctaggart/SourceLink/issues/192 which says running sourcelink print-urls will print "embed" but mine doesn't, perhaps this is a hint:

[image]

Has anyone got this to work successfully? If so can you tell what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I'm not an expert, but perhaps this is useful? https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jimgries/2007/07/06/why-does-visual-studio-require-debugger-symbol-files-to-exactly-match-the-binary-files-that-they-were-built-with/

Comment: It is a "it doesn't work question".  Plowing through the "not yet implemented in VS" articles is doggone painful, they are working past each other badly as of late.  But it should have all been sorted out in 15.8.8.  Just make sure you are using the latest debugging engine: Tools > Options > Debugging > General, "Use Managed Compatibility Mode" should be unchecked.  Beyond that a disk reformat or VS reinstall gets attractive.

Comment: Can we have a look at your Symbols PDB paths (Tools menu > Options > Debugging > Symbols) and can you show us a screenshot of the Modules (Debug Menu > Windows > Modules) highlighting the row where your PDB is loaded?

Comment: I'll try a different machine/fresh install/VM etc etc and report back. Has anyone actually had this working?

Comment: @HansPassant you were right. I'm not sure what the minimum I needed to do, but I bought a new SSD installed Windows 10 and VS 2017 and it works!!!! If you post this as the answer I'll accept it, bounty is open for another 3 hours.

Comment: Did you set [`Enable source link support`](https://github.com/ctaggart/SourceLink)?

Comment: This is already answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7311537/how-do-i-embed-source-into-pdb-and-have-debuggers-use-it

Comment: as well as here  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42714352/embedding-c-sharp-sources-in-pdb-with-new-csproj

Comment: @divyang4481 No, the 2 linked questions don't have answers for this question. The first link doesn't have a real answer, even though the question is very similar to this one. The second link is asking how to embed the PDB/sources into a nuget package, but not actually providing info on how to get VS to debug such a package.

Answer (score 2):

***Easiest way is to go to:***

`Debug -> Windows -> Modules`

Inside this list, you should be able to find your assembly (dll/exe).

`Right click it -> Load Symbols`

It will ask for where to load the symbols from.

Navigate to the directory where your matching .pdb file is.

It should auto load.  Stepping into, or having uncaught errors in this referenced assembly should trigger a break in that code, or ask you to navigate to the code file that corresponds to the file that threw the error.

In our process, we generally have to navigate to the nuget cache to find the pdbs for our installed nuget packages.  `(%UserProfile%/nuget/packages/YourPackage/VersionNumber/../..)`

We also package up the source with those packages and navigate to those `/nuget/packages .cs` files as well, though, any `corresponding .cs` file should allow it to load.

Comment: There is not a PDB file. The OP is using the Embedded option for the PDB, so its actually in the exe or dll.